# Mail.app plugins & Mac App Store

Tags: macos, email, plugins, app-store

Does anyone know if the Mac App Store is allowing third party plugins for the Mail.app? With the new release of Mountain Lion, the security architecture will sandbox every signed application (and thus Mail) so that the process of installing a plugin is very limited.

The question is: since a plugin must use a private API (Mail.app doesn't expose APIs) and access private data from another application, how can this be accomplished within Mac App Store rules? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never could publish plugins through the Mac App Store. The rules only allow for self-contained apps. You also couldn't sell an app that does nothing more than installing your plugin - the rules forbid apps to install any code in shared locations. And with the sandbox it's not possible either.

Comment: I supposed so... That is the rule which is present right from the beginning in the Mac App Store. However, with ML, there will be major restrictions on what you can distribute by other means. Do you think there's a chance to overcome this limitation?

Comment: @luca you can still distribute your app/plugin through other means. The default setting on Gatekeeper (the security feature that checks for app signatures) is set to "Mac Store and identified developers". In order to avoid the warning dialog to the user, you need to be a member of the Mac developer program (approx. $99/yr) and sign your plugin with your mac dev ID/cert. You can distribute it however you'd like

Answer (score 0):

Your application would need to be usable without the plugin present.  [MsgFiler](http://msgfiler.com/) offers a good example: it works, albeit slowly, by itself, and offers a plugin downloadable separately from the App Store which speeds it up.